# Rails: Managing Javascript Plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-plugins

I am developing a website when i have third-party plugins (javascript plugins, with css files and images) and i don't want to separate the plugin between stylesheets and javascript, i want to keep the plugins folder, and each plugin with the javascript and the stylesheet.

And i use different plugins in different pages of the webapp. So i put a "plugins" folder inside "vendor/assets" but i don't know how to load them in the webpage.

Do you know how can i do that? or do you have any advice for working with javascript plugins?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your application.css:

```
@import "/vendor/assets/plugins/css-stuff.css";
```

and in your application.js, try this:

```
<script src="/vendor/assets/plugins/javascript-stuff.js"></script>
```

That should work for you, but if not, then say something here.